# xamarin don't build proper apk with android sdk

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin

Yesterday I was able to build apk files.
Since I have add lots of pictures and ressources to theme the app, and when I want to test it on my device, Visual Studio build me one app that crash.

I set the "Release" mode, I go to TOOL>Publish application, I create a keystore and I build the apk.

I put the code to "Disable Debugging" and I've made the manifest.

When I tried to install it, it works, but the app crash.

The application works perfectly with the emulator.

The weight hasn't really change (some Ko) but the app MUST be bigger because of all the pictures I've put, so something is wrong...

Thanks to help me :-)

Comment: You may try to debug using the `adb` and see what exactly is happening when your app crashes.  Maybe post that log to help people try to figure out exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I unchecked the "Use Shared Runtime" in the properties>Mono android options:

[image: mono android options]